# export & sync contacts Thunderbird?

Tags: contacts

How to synchronize address books used in Thunderbird (gmail+EDS contact integration and local)? Necessary export and sync AddressBook with UbuntuOne Contacts. Or will only manual editing U1 Contacts? Please make the extension "UbuntuOne contacts sync" for Thunderbird.

Comment: Paulus, you're using a lot of shorthand here. Can you expand on your question so that folks can take a stab at answering it? You can already sync UbuntuOne contacts via Thunderbird's address book. Do you need help enabling that? Or are you looking for something else?